# retrieve amount of male/female participants

Tags: civievent, api

I would like to retrieve the amount of male/female participants of an event.
So far I am able to retrieve the total amount of registered people.
How can I get a number for the amount of male and female participants?

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Participant', 'getcount', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'event_id' => 66,
  'status_id' => array("Registered", "Pending from pay later", "Pending from incomplete transaction", "Partially paid", "Pending refund"),
  'options' => array('limit' => 9999),
));
```

Comment: Are you asking for any way to get the info or specifically how to do it from the API?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be answering your question, but did you look at civisualize? its latest version contains a visualisation for events, with a filter based on the gender...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can do that with an advanced search by simply selecting the correct event and the status being registered and then under demographics choosing the gender that you want

Answer (score 0):

Gender is a field available as a column on http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/25?reset=1 - so you could both show it, and filter by it. The later also lets you filter by 'not one of' 'male, female, transgender' in case you have contacts with no gender recorded